# Is there a way to erase the masked part of a model (sculp mode) without select the parts in edit mode? (Blender 2.8)

Tags: sculpting

It is easier select in sculpt mode. Thanks.

I add more information:

I need to erase the masked parts.

[image]

Comment: Please expand your question with more information, right now it's fairly vague. You can also add screenshots to clarify your question.

Comment: maybe with the new mask tool in 2.81, (under mask, mask extract) you can invert your selection and mask extract your mesh?